# How to wiggle an animation loop on a material node (brick texture)?

Tags: python, animation, materials

I want to wiggle an animation loop on a material node (brick texture) to be specific, i want to wiggle the bias value how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *Input > Value* Node with start and end keyframes (keyframe values can both be zero). Open the *Graph Editor* with the *Value* node selected and choose *Add Modifier* from the N-Panel on the right. Depending on your prefered type of 'wiggle', you can try "Noise" or "Cycles".

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You can also directly modify the keyframed *Bias* value of the *Brick Texture*, but it's more flexible to have a Value Node, so you could pass the wiggle simultaneously to a second shader effect, for example.